# \hat over italic letters is not centered horizontally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, letterhead

When using

```
$\hat{a}$
```

in LaTeX, the hat is actually aligned slightly left of the a's true head… Is there any common way to fix this?

As I think that this is a common issue, I didn't screenshot it, but if you want, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Starting point for comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $\hat a$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The centering is better with other math fonts like `mathptm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
  $\hat a$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
  $\hat a$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Another variant is using the symbol from a text font, e.g. `lmodern` that matches the standard Computer Modern fonts for math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\begin{document}
  $\textit{\^a}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: they all seem very fine. I'm currently using the beamer-class. So perhaps I should just change the font…