# \hat over italic letters is not centered horizontally 2

Tags: equations, lyx

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

$P=\hat{U\cdot}\hat{I}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cos\varphi$

\end{document}
```

I just looked at the hats enlarged on my top values. I am not satisfied with the alignment over the U.
I think the example in the previous article
[\hat over italic letters is not centered horizontally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85798/hat-over-italic-letters-is-not-centered-horizontally)
is not that serious.

The a with that hat still works for me. In my example the hat on the U is clearly out of focus. The solutions already presented do not work for me and it is also not an issue to use a different font because the appearance has to be consistent. The previous answers also do not really address the technical cause of this problem. That is why I am submitting the question again here.
The equation was originally generated with LyX.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want the hat over the pair `U\cdot`?

Comment: the accent is centred over U<cdot> not U as that is what you have specified in the argument.

Comment: Did you try `\hat{U}\cdot\hat{I}\cdot\cos\varphi`? Or, possibly better, with no `\cdot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(posting this note so that the question may be considered to have received an "official" answer)

As others have already commented on, don't include `\cdot` in the argument of `\hat`. Separately, do consider getting rid of the `\cdot` directives entirely; trust me, they won't be missed.

In the following screenshot, the `\cdot` directives are gone from lines 4 and 5; they differ in the presence or absence of a `\` "thinspace" spacer between `\hat{U}` and `\hat{I}`. In row 4, I added parentheses to help readers "parse" the full expression; in row 5, I moved the term `\tfrac{1}{2}` to the front as there's no good reason -- typographically speaking -- to stick it somewhere in the middle of the formula. Which solution is "better" is largely a matter of taste; some might prefer the tight look in row 5, while others might find it a bit too cramped. What really matters, in the end, is that you develop a consistent math writing style. If you do that, your readers will quickly adapt their reading approach to what you've written for them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat*' environment and '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    P&=\hat{U\cdot}\hat{I}\cdot\tfrac{1}{2}\cos\varphi &\qquad&\text{bad}\\
     &=\hat{U}\cdot\hat{I}\cdot\tfrac{1}{2}\cos\varphi &&\text{ok}\\
     &=\hat{U}\,\hat{I}\cdot\tfrac{1}{2}\cos\varphi    &&\text{better}\\
     &=\hat{U}\,\hat{I}(\tfrac{1}{2}\cos\varphi)       &&\text{even better?}\\     
     &=\tfrac{1}{2}\hat{U}\hat{I}\cos\varphi    &&\text{too cramped?} % no '\,' spacer
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the wrong bracketing was the mistake. I use Lyx's math editor. I didn't notice this problem there. I know that I can display the source code window in Lyx and I have activated this setting. Unfortunately, I didn't think of this kind of bug and didn't look closely at the source code. I thank all supporters.

Comment: I believe you and I deleted all unnecessary \cdot s in my document.

Comment: @Michael.H - I'm not a lyx user myself, and you didn't set the `lyx` tag when you posted your query, so I had no inkling as to why -- or, as the case may be here, lyx -- would write `\hat{U\cdot}`. Glad it's all got sorted out. :-)

Comment: I didn't know anything about the tag lyx so far. I've added the tag now. Perhaps you could update your Answer with my first missing factor 1/2 in front of cos. See my updated question. The error in LyX happened to me because I carelessly marked the area with the mouse over which the hat should be.

Comment: @Michael.H - Done. :-)

Comment: Also `\hat{U}\hat{I}\cdot\tfrac{1}{2}\cos\varphi` if one needs to make a derivation clearer. I'd not use the parentheses around the expression.

Comment: @egreg  - Done. :-)